# Get Last Selected Value of Select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using multiple options for Select2 and the data is loaded from a JSON source.

As I'm not sure how to explain it exactly I'll provide an example:

### List Options:

- A
- B
- C

If I choose C, then

```
$("#select2").change(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
```

Results: [C]

However, If I then choose A I would get [A, C]

If I then choose B I get [A, B, C]

I would preferably want it to append so I would get [C, A, B]. However being able to find the last selected option would be alright. I have tried :last and other answers but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance.

My script for Select2:

```
$.getJSON('profile/Skills.json', function (json) {
        var mainList = [];
        for (var TradeName in json) {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(TradeName)) {
                var item = json[TradeName];
                mainList.push(item.TradeName);            
            }
        }       
        $(".chyeaSelect").select2({
            data:mainList
        });
    });
```

Comment: I believe it might be helpful to see more of the code, as doing a basic alert on a list like that wouldn't have those results: http://codepen.io/stufu/pen/YqBZyV - what does the JSON request look like?

Comment: @StuFu this is using https://select2.github.io/

Comment: Sorry - didn't see the tag! Updated my pen to pull it in but it still might help to see how you're pulling the data in via Select2

Comment: @StuFu Updated. Anything else let me know

Comment: I updated my pen using your exact code and with a dummy feed, not sure if I'm seeing the issue

Comment: @StuFu I'm trying to retrieve the last selected value. From what I understand Select2 takes the values and inserts them in to an object. I'm trying to retrieve the last selected value. The problem is that if the value selected is before another selected value, the latter selected value is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
$.getJSON('https://demo8858242.mockable.io/list', function (json) {
        var mainList = [];
        for (var TradeName in json) {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(TradeName)) {
                var item = json[TradeName];
                mainList.push(item.TradeName);            
            }
        }       
        $(".select1").select2({
            data:mainList
        });
    }); 

  var array = [];

  $(".select1").change(function(){
    //alert($(this).val());
    array.unshift($(this).val());
    alert(array);
  });

// Alternate
//$(".select1").change(function(){
//    alert($(this).val());
//    //$('.selected').prepend($(this).val());
//});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/stufu/pen/YqBZyV)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm not looking to add or remove from an array. I'm looking to find the new value selected. The issue is the way select2 adds items to the object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's too late for your problem, but maybe this can help someone else.
I use :

```
$('#select2').on('select2:select', function(e: any) {
    console.log(e.params.data.id);
});
```

Same with "select2:unselect".

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'on `select2:selecting` event to get last selected value (before change event) also you can get the old selected value

```
$('#selectId').on("select2:selecting", function (e) {
            e.params.args.data.id or e.params.args.data.value//new value
            $('#selectId').val()//old Value
            if (...)
        e.preventDefault();//to prevent changes
    });
```