# Get Last Selected of Select2 v4

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using multiple options for Select2 and the data is loaded from a JSON source.

As I'm not sure how to explain it exactly I'll provide an example:

### List Options:

- A
- B
- C

If I choose C, then

Results: [C]

If I then choose A I would get [A, C]

If I then choose B I get [A, B, C]

I would preferably want it to append so I would get [C, A, B]. However being able to find the last selected option would be alright. I have tried :last and other answers but nothing seems to work.

I've noticed in previous versions of Select2 this issue was not present. Downgrading is not an option.

Thanks in advance.

My script for Select2:

```
$.getJSON('profile/Skills.json', function (json) {
        var mainList = [];
        for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
            var item = json[i];
            mainList.push({id: item, text: item});
        }           
        var mySelect = $(".chyeaSelect").select2({
            data:mainList
        }); 
        mySelect.on("select2:select", function(){
            alert(mySelect.val());
        });
        mySelect.on("select2:unselect", function(){
            alert("Unselected");
        });
    });
```

Comment: What differs from your previous question???? [Get Last Selected Value of Select2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094429/get-last-selected-value-of-select2)

Comment: mySelect.on("select2:select", function(e){
            alert(e.params.data.text, e.params.data.id);
        });